# Is there a way to set default date when navigating to a new month or year in date range picker?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, daterangepicker

I am using DateRangePicker library in a project and faced an issue, my goal was when opening the calendar for the first time, the current date is selected by default(done) and when navigating to another month or year the same day becomes selected as I go so that there is always a selected day in the calendar. there are some speical cases to consider like if the selected day is 31 and the next month doesn't contain it so it should select 30 instead and so on but it's not the problem now. The problem is I tried to use setStartDate() to do that but it didn't work, although the date changes correctly when I logged it but it's not selected in the calendar (missing the css class that highlights it). So does anyone knows how to fix that or what to use instead to achieve my goal?

Thanks

```
  ngAfterViewChecked() {
    if (this.isCalendarShown) {
      var element = $(document.getElementsByClassName("daterangepicker show-calendar"))
          .filter(function(){
            return $(this).css('display') === 'block';
          }).get(0);
      var monthSelected = element.getElementsByClassName("monthselect")[0];
      if (monthSelected != null) {
        var month = (<HTMLInputElement>monthSelected).value;
        var year = (<HTMLInputElement>element.getElementsByClassName("yearselect")[0]).value;
        var isStartDateExist = element.getElementsByClassName("left")[0].querySelector(".start-date");
        var isStartDateValid = element.getElementsByClassName("left")[0].querySelector(".off.start-date");
        if ( isStartDateExist != null && isStartDateValid == null ) {
          this.currentMonth = month;
          this.currentYear = year;
        }
        if (month != this.currentMonth || year != this.currentYear) {
          const  date = String(parseInt(month)+1).padStart(2, '0')+'/01/'+year;
          this.picker.setStartDate(date.toString());
          this.picker.setEndDate(date.toString());
        } 
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: I have also faced this same issue the date picker is selecting the date but the color was not changing this is not related to any CSS. It is environment-specific so when I was doing that in my local and select the date was picked but the color not changed but that same issue was not there on dev, staging, and production environment. I know this is silly but sometimes things work in a strange way.

Comment: .mat-calendar-body-selected {
    background-color: $accent-green;
} add this class to your css file and replace the color you want.